# SQL: How to check for each row in Table A if there is a relationship with each row in Table B

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have three tables.

| TABLE A |
| --- |
| A_ID |

| TABLE B |
| --- |
| B_ID |

| JOIN TABLE |
| --- |
| A_ID |
| B_ID |

For every row in `TABLE A`, I am trying to check whether or not it is connected to `TABLE B` in `JOIN TABLE`.

Ideally, the output I'm trying to get back looks something like this:

[image: Pivot Table]
...

Is this possible with SQL?

Comment: Your join table design looks odd and I can't figure out how you get to your desired outcome , please add table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of a common pivot-table solution for MySQL called *conditional aggregation*.

```
SELECT A_ID,
  COALESCE(MAX(CASE B_ID WHEN 1 THEN TRUE END), FALSE) AS TABLE_B_ENTRY_1,
  COALESCE(MAX(CASE B_ID WHEN 2 THEN TRUE END), FALSE) AS TABLE_B_ENTRY_2
FROM TABLE_A
LEFT OUTER JOIN JOIN_TABLE USING (A_ID)
GROUP BY A_ID;
```

You do have to explicitly code a column expression for each distinct value of `B_ID` you want to search for. There's no way in SQL to make a query that automatically expands the number of columns based on the data read in the same query.